# Passing structure to parameter of type `const struct` does not produce a warning

Tags: c, struct, constants

In the following example not-const qualified pointer `b` is passed to `func`, which expects a pointer to a const qualified type. Hence, I would expect the compiler to issue a warning. However, if I compile this program with clang and `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` there is no warning. Why is that?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 5


struct Bear {
    int n;
    int v;
    int *data;
};


void func (const struct Bear *bear, int *data, const size_t n)
{
    memcpy (bear->data, data, n);    
}


int main (void)
{
    int arr[N];
    int *mem = malloc (N*sizeof (int));
    if (mem == NULL) return -1;

    struct Bear *b = &(struct Bear){1, 2, mem};
    func (b, arr, N);

    free (mem);
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, if I change the line in which the structure is initialized to

```
const struct Bear *b = &(const struct Bear){1, 2, mem};
```

there is still no warning. I understand that `const` in a struct declaration is applied to its fields, hence, `bear->v = 11;` in `func` is clearly an error (and produces a warning). However, this does not seem to be true for pointers.

Is this undefined behavior? What am I missing here?

Comment: You can pass a non-const to a const.  The warning occurs when you try to pass a const to a non-const, since that suggests the pointer target could be modified.  For instance, things like `strcpy` take a `const char *` source argument, indicating that it is not modified, but you can pass any `char *` as that argument.

Comment: Declaring a pointer as a pointer-to-const in a function declaration simply tells the compiler (and the programmer using the function) that the function won't change the object that the pointer references. It doesn't require you to pass a pointer-to-const. In other words, from the programmer's point of view, the use of const in a function declaration is nothing more than documentation about the function's behavior. From the compiler's point of view, it's an optimization hint.

Comment: Note that `memcpy (bear->data, data, n);` doesn't change the pointer `bear->data` but only the content to which it points. The prototype of `memcpy` guaranties it since the first operant is a pointer with `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Converting Pointers

When calling a function with a prototype, the argument (`b`, of type `struct Bear *`) is converted to the type of the corresponding parameter (`bear`, of type `const struct Bear *`), per C 2018 6.5.2.2 7:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters…

The constraints for assignment in 6.5.16.1 1 include allowing conversion to a pointer to the same type but with added qualifiers such as `const`:

> … the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and … both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right…

Also, conversions of pointers are discussed in C 2018 6.3.2.3, where paragraph 2 says:

> For any qualifier *q*, a pointer to a non-*q*-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the *q*-qualified version of the type…

Quite simply, the qualifiers are restrictions on the use of a thing; they say it is intended for some subset of potential uses of the thing. The `const` qualifier says the object will be used only to read its value, not to modify its value.<sup>1</sup> So it is perfectly fine to pass a pointer to a thing that **may** be modified to a function that indicates it **will not** modify it. So the rules of the C standard are written to permit this.

### `const` Applied to Structures

> I understand that const in a struct declaration is applied to its fields…

If the structure is `const`, the structure member `data` is `const`, but that member is a pointer. So this just means the **pointer** is `const`. That does not mean **what it points to** is `const`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The `const` qualifier is not a complete barrier to modifying an object. If an object was defined without `const`, a pointer to it for which `const` has been added can be converted (with a cast) back to a pointer without `const` and used to modify the object.